# Error: System.InvalidOperationException: ' Could not initialize because missing CategoryName.'

Tags: c#, windows, forms, visual-studio-2019, designer

The line of code provoking the error is the following:

```
 ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.performanceCounter1)).EndInit();
```

Software:
Visual Studio 2019
Programming Language:
C#
Note:
Code was generated by the Windows Forms Designer

Comment: Any use? - https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t612537/failed-to-initialize-because-categoryname-is-missing

Comment: Maybe you can try to set performanceCounter1's CategoryName, CounterName and InstanceName in Form1.Designer.cs via code.